# Concatenate distinct surname values for each distinct name value

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, group-by, distinct

What i want to achieve is the concatenation of all DISTINCT surname values for each DISTINCT name values.

What i have manage is the concatenation of DISTINCT name values but unfortunately all surname values.

Below is my code:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[Name], 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+ST1.Surname  AS [text()]
            FROM [Ext_Names] ST1
            WHERE ST1.[Name] = ST2.[Name]
            ORDER BY ST1.[Name]
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Surname]
FROM [Ext_Names] ST2
```

**Sample Data**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Comment: FYI, if you do have a list over 1000 characters long, this will truncate your data. Rather than taking the rightmost characters, with `SUBSTRING`, you are far better off removing the first character with `STUFF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the distinct values first, then aggregate. If you are running SQL Server 2017 or higher, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select name, string_agg(surname, ',') within group (order by surname) surnames
from (select distinct name, surname from ext_names) t
group by name
```

Comment: i m receiving an error `Column 't.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, @Error1004 . It clear that GMB forgot to add the `GROUP BY`, but the error is telling you that and how to fix it ;)

Comment: @Larnu i just add `GROUP BY name` at the end it s seems to work. but i m not sure that s way i ask to confirm

Comment: Thanks both of you! really appreciate.

Comment: In case i have an SQL Server version lower than 2017 what to you propose?

Answer (score 0):

You can done with this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[Name], SUBSTRING((SELECT  ','+ T.Surename  AS [text()] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ST1.Surename FROM Ext_Names ST1 WHERE ST1.Name = ST2.Name  ) T ORDER BY T.Surename FOR XML PATH('')),2,1000) [SureEname]
FROM Ext_Names ST2
```